# How do I make clickable images return unique values?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make a Monty Hall simulator.  The user is presented with three identical pictures of a door, lined up in a row.  They choose their door by clicking on image one, two, or three.

I'm unable to figure out a way to get that value into JavaScript.  What I mean is, I don't know how to tell JavaScript that the user clicked, say, door one and *then* assign the value of **1** to a variable which I can then play around with.  Here's the code (for what it's worth.  I've not managed to come within a thousand miles of a solution):

```js
// ELEMENT VARIABLES
const instructions = document.getElementById('instructions');
const startGameButton = document.getElementById('startGameButton');
const door1 = document.getElementById('door1');
const door2 = document.getElementById('door2');
const door3 = document.getElementById('door3');



// CHOOSING THE PRIZE DOOR

let prizeDoor = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3 + 1);


// LOADING ALL EVENT LISTENERS

function loadEventListeners() {
    startGameButton.addEventListener('click', removeInstructionsAndButtonAndMakeDoorsAppear);
}

loadEventListeners();

function removeInstructionsAndButtonAndMakeDoorsAppear() {
    instructions.innerHTML = '';
    door1.style.display = 'block';
    door2.style.display = 'block';
    door3.style.display = 'block';
}
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Acme&family=Dancing+Script&family=Festive&family=Lato:wght@100;300;400;700&family=Tourney:wght@100;200;300;400;500&display=swap');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Festive&family=Tourney:wght@100;200;300;400;500&display=swap');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Acme&family=Festive&family=Tourney:wght@100;200;300;400;500&display=swap');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Acme&family=Festive&family=Lato:wght@100;300;400;700&family=Tourney:wght@100;200;300;400;500&display=swap');

*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
    font-size: 62.5%;
    font-family: 'Lato', 'Arial', sans-serif;
}

body {
    background-color: rgb(178, 237, 252);
}


.show-title {
    font-family: 'Dancing Script';
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 5rem;
    word-spacing: 3rem;
    letter-spacing: 1rem;
    margin-top: 1rem;
}

.introduction {
    position: absolute;
    font-family: 'Acme';
    top: 40%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    font-size: 3rem;
    text-align: center;
}

.rules {
    font-size: 1.8rem;
    margin-top: 2rem;
}

.start-game {
    font-family: 'Tourney';
    color: white;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    margin-top: 2rem;
    padding-top: .8rem;
    padding-bottom: .8rem;
    padding-left: 2.5rem;
    padding-right: 2.5rem;
    background-color: black;
    border-radius: 10px;;
}

.door-container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 70vh;

}

.door-styling {
    margin-left: 8rem;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.door {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>MONTY HALL</title>
</head>
<body>

        <div class="title">
            <h1 class="show-title">THE MONTY HALL SHOW</h1>
        </div>

        <div class="introduction" id="instructions">
            <p class="welcome">Welcome to the Monty Hall Show.</p>

            <p class="rules">The rules are simple.  You'll be shown three doors, behind one of which is a jpeg of a briefcase full of cash.  Behind the others? <br><br>Goats.  <br><br>Yeah.  That's right.  Dirty, smelly, ungrateful goats.</p>

            <p class="rules">All you have to do is pick the door behind which you think lies the cash.  I will then open <em>one</em> of the two remaining doors.  You'll then be given an opportunity to stick with your original choice, or switch to the one remaining door.</p>

            <p class="rules">May the odds be ever in your favour.</p>
            <button class="start-game" id="startGameButton">I understand</button>
        </div>
        <div class="door-container">

                <img src="img/doors.jpg" class="door door-styling" id="door1">

                <img src="img/doors.jpg" class="door door-styling" id="door2">

                <img src="img/doors.jpg" class="door door-styling" id="door3">

        </div>




<script src="app.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

I've been working on this for about five hours today, trying everything I can think of and googling my ass off, all to no avail. Any help you could provide would be gratefully appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Add this function to your javascript:

```
function doorClicked(doorNumber) {
  console.log('Clicked', doorNumber);
  // store to variable and do your thing
}
```

and in the HTML add `onclick` to your door images:

```html
<img src="img/doors.jpg" class="door door-styling" id="door1" onclick="doorClicked(1)">
<img src="img/doors.jpg" class="door door-styling" id="door2" onclick="doorClicked(2)">
<img src="img/doors.jpg" class="door door-styling" id="door3" onclick="doorClicked(3)">
```

Comment: was just writing that <3

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a good approach to do it. Just create an event on click and read the door id number. Good luck!

```js
let selectedDoor = 0;

let doors = document.getElementsByClassName("door");
for (let i = 0; i < doors.length; i++) {
    doors[i].addEventListener("click", function(){
       selectedDoor = parseInt(this.id.split("door")[1]);
       console.log(selectedDoor);
    });
}
```

```css
img {
    width: 150px;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://images.ole.com.ar/2021/07/10/g0_-ovqlt_720x0__1.jpg" class="door door-styling" id="door1">

<img src="https://images.ole.com.ar/2021/07/10/g0_-ovqlt_720x0__1.jpg" class="door door-styling" id="door2">

<img src="https://images.ole.com.ar/2021/07/10/g0_-ovqlt_720x0__1.jpg" class="door door-styling" id="door3">
```

Answer (score 0):

learn to use event delegation:

```js
const 
  allDoors  = document.querySelector('#door-container')
, prizeDoor = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3 + 1);
  ;
allDoors.onclick = ({target}) =>
  {
  if (!target.matches('img')) return  // ignore clicks on spaces

  let good_door = (prizeDoor == target.dataset.door)
  
  allDoors.classList.add('no-more-click')
  target.classList.add( (good_door?'good':'wrong'))

  console.log(`expected is ${prizeDoor}, door clicked is ${target.dataset.door}, => ${good_door} `)
  }
```

```css
#door-container img {
  cursor  : pointer;
  padding : 2px;
  border  : 5px solid grey;
  margin  : 2px;
}
#door-container img:hover {
  border-color   : yellow;
}
#door-container img.good {
  border-color   : green;
}
#door-container img.wrong {
  border-color   : red;
}
.no-more-click {
  pointer-events : none;
}
```

```html
<div id="door-container">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1003/150" data-door="1">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1025/150" data-door="2">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1074/150" data-door="3">
</div>
```